# Spring NoClassDefFoundError for com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedCollator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websphere-liberty

I'm totally puzzled for the below error. I have no idea where is this coming from as it is not used in my application. I tried adding this dependency in war file but it did not work.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedCollator )
*** STACK TRACE:
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1221)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1005)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:75)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:938)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1061)
com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:417)
com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:376)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:466)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:331)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:70)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:503)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:573)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:954)
com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1043)
com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:239)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
```

Comment: I don't see RuleBasedCollator in the Liberty Codebase, so I'll speculate that there's some app or library that's misconfigured on the "ET" server.  Server start --clean might also be worth a try.

Comment: Tried didn't help. I will test by changing class loading order from parentFirst to parentLast

Comment: Did not help application failed to start with parentLast approach

Comment: @BruceT. It was the IMS connector i.e. IMS1323.rar which had this class but on WLP infra team used IMS1412.rar. After fixing that I am facing
``ICO0005E: com.ibm.connector2.ims.ico.IMSTCPIPManagedConnection@211fbf61.receive() error. A communication error occurred during sending or receiving the IMS message. clientID=[HWSVZYOH] [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]] )``
I tried fixing it by including
``<connectionFactory  id="ims" authDataAlias="ims_user" jndiName="eis/IMSSyncNonPersistent" purgePolicy="EntirePool" maxPoolSize="50">``
but it did not help

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier to take an exact copy of a server from a working environment, and then change it only as needed for the nonworking environment, being careful to keep it working.  Or take exact copies of servers from failing and working environments, and diff them thoroughly to find what's wrong with the failing environment.  It's probably another misconfiguration like "wrong rar file".

Comment: @BruceT. Figured out the issue the IMS endpoint in ET needs a SSL certificate. It blocks the request if it is absent. Is it possible for you to share a sample connectionManager config with SSL enabled ? I want to pass SSL certificate to connection request I am making to IMS thru connectionManager Configuration in server.xml

Comment: I don't have one, but if you clone this repo and grep all the xml files, there might be an example in a test case. https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty.  Docs are here but are rather light on examples.  https://openliberty.io/ . You might also try asking another question titled "connectionManager config for websphere liberty" and see if someone who knows that topic responds.

Answer (score 0):

As it was a nested exception thrown by spring, I figured out the flow of the occurrence of the error.It was during hitting a transaction using a third party ims library. I looked into the library and voila the jar ICU4J was missing. After adding it the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My solution;

Eclipse --> Help --> Eclipse Marketplace

Install the following package.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW98b.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IntelliJ then close and restart the IDE